# Is there anyway to install twain module in python 3

Tags: python, twain, python-2to3

I want to install the [Python TWAIN module](http://twainmodule.sourceforge.net/) in Python 3. But in the docs it says:

> Python versions 2.1 through 2.5 are supported.

Can I convert it using `2to3`?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: Please answer and complete the installation at-least with python27. 2016 we are stuck

Comment: @YumYumYum You can install twain module for python using [pytwain](https://github.com/denisenkom/pytwain) module.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `twain` for Python 3 using the `.whl` method.

First, you need to download the `.whl` file: [twainmodule - Python Extension Packages for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twainmodule). Pick the one that matches your Python 3 version (example: I downloaded the `twain‑1.0.4‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl`).

Important note, I specifically chose the file ending with `win32.whl` because I had troubles using the 64-bit version. For example, the scaner I was working with only supported 32-bit Twain.

Then, install `wheel` with `pip install wheel`.

Install twain using `pip install /path/to/twain‑1.0.4‑cpXX‑cpXX‑XX.whl`

Answer (score 0):

Use [past](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/past/) module which provides an experimental translation package to help with importing and using old Python 2 modules in a Python 3 environment.

So install your package with pip

```
pip3 install twain --no-compile   # to ignore SyntaxErrors
```

And use next code to import twain in your `python3` code :

```
from past import autotranslate
autotranslate(['twain'])

import twain


# use twain .......
```

Comment: When I try this command  `pip3 install twain --no-compile`  , I have got an message like : `Downloading/unpacking twain
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement twain
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for twain
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\PB\pip\pip.log`      What does it mean?

Comment: Please answer and complete the installation. 2016 we are stuck