# Installing Twain Module on Python 3.4 on Windows

Tags: python, twain

I followed this [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747074/is-there-anyway-to-install-twain-module-in-python-3) but got an error message :

```
C:\Users\PB>pip install twain --no-compile
Downloading/unpacking twain
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requiremen
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for twain
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\PB\pip\pip.log
```

I researched and found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222104/no-distributions-at-all-found-for-some-package) and try this command:

```
pip install twain == 1.0.5 --allow-unverified twain
```

and got an error message :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
   File "C:\Python3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257,in run   
InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
File "C:\Python3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
File "C:\Python3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
     req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
File "C:\Python3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line2606,
in parse
reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
File "C:\Python3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py",line2532 
in parse_requirements
raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '==')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\PB\pip\pip.log
```

Howcan I solve install twain ?

Answer (score 0):

you can download code for python 3.x from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twainmodule

and install by manually

Comment: I downloaded `twain-1.0.4-py3-source.zip` and run in cmd this command : `python setup.py install` gives me error `File "setup.py", line 4, in <modul
    from numpy import get_include
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'` . I try to install numpy but can not install numpy on python 3.4 . HOw can I solve this ?

Comment: Well, you can try to download 'twain-1.0.4-cp34-none-win32.whl',and use pip to install like 'C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install twain-1.0.4-cp34-none-win32.whl'