# Installing TWAIN on Python 3.4 on x64 Windows

Tags: python, numpy, twain

I try to install [twain](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twain/1.0.5) x64 Windows.I use Python 3.4 .I followed this [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803167/installing-twain-module-on-python-3-4-on-windows/34803747#34803747) . I downloaded [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twainmodule) link in zip file . When I try to command in cmd `python setup.py install` gave an error : `no module named numpy` . I researched and installed numpy . Then I command in cmd `python setup.py install` gave an error :

```
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
    ValueError: ['path']
```

There always got an error , do you think is twain module runs in my machine because it says 32 bits operatins system only but I think it can runs in x64, so what is the next step to I can solve this problem ?

Comment: are you trying to install it onto 32 bit python or 64 bit?

Comment: @JamesKent 64 bit python

Comment: that might be part of your problem, if twain contains any compiled modules they would not work in 64 bit python.

Comment: @JamesKent anyway to install it 64 bit ?

Comment: if that module has only been compiled against 32 bit then you would have to get access to the source and compile it yourself, and from a quick glance at the website looks as if the source is not available. so the short answer looks like a no.